# last child selector on unwrap element

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="title">A</div>
  <div class="title">B</div>
  <div class="content">Something</div>
</div>
```

How can I select `B` title without restructuring my html, and there might be C, D, E and more title be added in. I tried below css it doesn't work

Comment: Where's your CSS?

Comment: are you sure that the order of div in the above html won't change??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai will change but still have to select last .title within .tabs

Comment: the answer is simple, there is no way with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` selectors. Choose any of the below according to your needs.

**Solution: 1**

```
.tabs :nth-child(2){
  color:red;
}
```

**Solution: 2**

```
.tabs .title:nth-child(2){
  color:red;
}
```

**Solution: 3**

```
.tabs .title:nth-of-type(2){
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: what if title is dynamic and might have 3 or more item?

Comment: if the title is dynamic and you always want to highlight the second `title`. Then use `.tabs .title:nth-of-type(2){
  color:red;
}`

Comment: I don't want to second I want the last

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs .title:nth-child(2) {
    color : green;
}
```

Comment: what if title is dynamic and might have 3 or more item?

Comment: If you want every 2nd child to apply the color use:

.tabs .title:nth-child(2n+2) {
    color : green;
}

Comment: nope I don't want that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use case?